# RewriteRule Not Working on Home Page: {REQUEST_URI} Cloudflare

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cloudflare

I am currently using .htaccess to redirect users based on Cloudflare Country, however with my current configuration the home page fails to launch a redirect. I believe this is due to the "%{REQUEST_URI}" at the end of the url, and have not found any resources yet to answer this.

The goal is to alter the end of the domain ".com" to ".mx" or ".ca" on ALL pages INCLUDING the home page. Right now this works on ALL Pages, EXCEPT the home page.

My current configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^MX$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.mx
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.mx%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^CA$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.ca
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: There's nothing "wrong" with the rules you've posted that would suggest why it doesn't work for the "home page" only. (By "home page", I assume you mean the root URL `/`?) It certainly has nothing to do with `REQUEST_URI` - which is necessary for all requests, including the "home page". Why are you redirecting to `http`, not `https`? The regex on the 2nd conditions is not correct, but it is unlikely to make a difference anyway (unless `mx` exists in the domain). ie `.mx` should be `\.mx$`. However, if you are behind Cloudflare, are requests for the homepage even reaching your origin server?

Comment: What is your complete `.htaccess` file with these directives in-place? You may have a conflict.

Comment: The requests were not reaching the origin, due to extreme cache levels on the home page